# Using different footnote numbering styles at the same time

Tags: numbering, footnotes

How can I create the below pattern in LaTex?

[image]

I would like to have both numbering styles on almost all pages in a document, and a bit of distance between them. The numeric footnotes appear in a paragraph formatting.

Comment: It's impossible to know what you mean by “normal” and ”paragraph” footnotes without more context. Please include a minimal working example that shows how you're producing both types of footnotes (including the preamble showing any packages used).

Comment: Whatever the exact details of the problem, the bigfoot package is probably the answer.

Comment: Thank both of you for the answer. To be as clear as possible, I changed the whole question.

Comment: You might try [`manyfoot`.](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/manyfoot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with the manyfoot package

```
\usepackage[para]{manyfoot}% allow [para] option

\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{A}[alph] % define \footnoteA
%   for alphabetic paragraph footnotes
```

Oops, the question asked for alphabetic ordinary footnotes, not alphabetic paragraph footnotes. I don't see that manyfoot provides any mechanism for restyling footnotes. So either declare both sets of footnotes as "new" variants

```
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[alph] % define \footnoteA = alphabetic
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{N} % and \footnoteN = numeric in paragraph
```

or declare just the new alphabetic series while changing the numbering of regular footnotes

```
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\alph{footnote}} % \footnote uses letters
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{N} % and \footnoteN = numeric in paragraph
```

I initially recommend the bigfoot package since it fixes up and extends the manyfoot package. But it seems to not fill the line in para mode; I only see two notes on a line.

```
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{default}[alph]% default \footnote alphabetic
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{P} %  \footnoteP for numeric
```

A point in favor of bigfoot is the ability to apply declarations to the ordinary footnotes, called "default".

Comment: Thank you! Manyfoot package works. The only problem is that the alphabetical footnotes appear in a paragraph mode, not the numerical ones. Is there any way to do it vice versa (that is, numerical footnotes in the paragraph mode and alphabetical footnotes one per line)?

Comment: Oh sorry! I mis-followed the question. The original version with bigfoot implied how to do it, but that would only work for bigfoot. I'll look for it in manyfoot.

Answer (score 1):

The `memoir` class (a superset of the `book`, `report` and `article` classes) provides a variety of footnote styles, layouts, and numbering. For your case try this:

```
% footnoteprob.tex  SE 576072

\documentclass{memoir}

\paragraphfootnotes
\newfootnoteseries{X}
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteX}{\alph{footnoteX}}


\begin{document}

This is a test\footnoteX{This word ...} to show how to create\footnote{One ...}
two different kinds of footnotes with different numbering 
styles\footnote{The ...} at the same\footnote{Same} 
time\footnoteX{Two special ...}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to eliminate the line between those two types of footnotes?

Comment: @MoZ Yes. Do `\let\oldfootnoterule\footnoterule` `\renewcommand{\footnoterule{}`. To restore the rule do `\letfootnoterule\oldfootnoterule`.